# How can I know the size of an array in Blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I need something like this:

```
@if ($array.length > 0)
    {{-- expr --}}
@endif
```

is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? I don't know PHP well but I'm interested in Laravel since my host doesn't support Rails.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to at least determine the length in the controller and pass a Boolean to the view.

Comment: I had also thought of that, but I found it very cumbersome, well the php count function works ^^

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the PHP [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function to count the length of an array.

Answer (score 76):

It is possible with the `count` function, like so:

```
@if (count($array) > 0)
    {{-- expr --}}
@endif
```

Comment: Please, edit original post if it is an edit, or mark it as a solution if you discovered it by yourself.